# how to give condition to annotation django to return a boolean field

Tags: django, annotations

i'm trying to give condition to an annotate field to return a `BooleanField`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    date_of_expire = models.DateTimeField()
```

my views.py

```
from django.db.models import Case,When,BooleanField
def lists(request):
    lists = Employee.objects.annotate(is_expire=Case(When(
        date_of_expire__lte=timezone.now()
        ),output_field=BooleanField())).order_by('-date_of_expire')
    #others
```

but it doesnt work , still return all existing data even some of object's `date_of_expire` is less than current time

is there something else i should try please ?

Comment: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/annotate-a-condition-as-booleanfield.html

Comment: wow that was magic ,thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

as Mr @willem Van Onsem mentioned a link in the comment

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField,ExpressionWrapper,Q

lists = Employee.objects.annotate(is_expire=ExpressionWrapper(Q(date_of_expire__lte=timezone.now()),output_field=BooleanField()).order_by('-date_of_expire')
```

[ExpressionWrapper](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/pattern/annotate-a-condition-as-booleanfield.html)